# Windows authentication requirement when trying to connect under another user

Tags: content-manager, sdl-tridion, custom-page

I try to connect to the CoreService using next credentials:

_client.Impersonate("Domain\MTSUser");

But I still get an error related to my current Windows account:
{"Impersonation by this user requires the @MyWindowsAccount account to be configured as impersonation user."}

What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually I am not sure how you connect, by which User. 
You do not connect to core service with that piece of code you pasted. You connect to core service by providing Username and Password during the instantiation of the client.

Once you are connected, you can Impersonate to another user (in this case you are trying to Impersonate to MTSUser) where System is saying to you that you cannot do so because your user (which you used initially to connect to core service) has no Impersonation Rights.

If you want to allow certain users to be able to impersonate into ANY user, you can do so in Tridion MMC snapin Console, but be vary, this is realy big security risk!

Answer (score 3):

You do not want just anyone to be able to impersonate any other user. So to use the Impersonate method, you will have to specifically add the current user as an "impersonation user" (within the Content Manager configuration) -- meaning that user *is* allowed to impersonate *anyone* else. You should only ever do that with 'system' accounts that you use to run your code - not regular users.